# Changing the page that my ASP.net site redirects to when a user reopens a page after clicking remember me on login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, remember-me

How would I go about changing the page that my ASP.net site redirects to when a user reopens a page after clicking remember me on login. The remember me function works but the user stays of the home page. I would like the user to be redirected to another page instead.

The site is an ASP.net site written in C# please comment if you need more information.

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                //                      return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "MainPage");
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                //return View(model);
                return RedirectToAction("", "");
        }
    }
```

This is the code for the "Login" method. For some reason it isn't reaching the "return RedirectToAction" section. I've added breakpoints and the switch(result) is "success".

I can also confirm that the cookie ".ASPnet.ApplicationCookie" is being generated as I can see it in the chrome debug menu.

Many Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
private IActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
        {
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
            }
        }
```

Using:

```
return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
```